# Octave - putting words into vector

Tags: octave

I am working on creating an email filter. I have a sample email which says something like this:

> Hi how are you lets meet up

I want to put each one of these words into a vector. I am looking for something like this.

```
Words = ['Hi';'how','are','you','lets','meet','up']
```

and when I enter

words(1), I want it to display Hi.

I really don't know where to start. I found answers for different languages such as Ruby and JS. But not for Octave.

Comment: You might look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFstrsplit).

Comment: Short but to the point. I will try that once I get home. Thanks @beaker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Andy's answer about cells, you can collect your email as a string and process it using string operations such as `strtok`, `strsplit` etc. e.g.

```
octave:7> s = 'Hi how are you lets meet up';
octave:8> words = strsplit(s, ' ')
  words = 
  {
    [1,1] = Hi
    [1,2] = how
    [1,3] = are
    [1,4] = you
    [1,5] = lets
    [1,6] = meet
    [1,7] = up
  }
octave:9> words{1}
  ans = Hi
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use Cell Arrays of Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Cell-Arrays-of-Strings.html#Cell-Arrays-of-Strings):

```
octave:1> words = {'hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'lets', 'meet', 'up'};
octave:2> words{1}
ans = hi
```

and you can use indexing:

```
octave:4> words{3:4}
ans = are
ans = you
```

if you struggle why this returns a different result:

```
octave:5> words(3:4)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = are
  [1,2] = you 
}
```

[then read here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Indexing-Cell-Arrays.html#Indexing-Cell-Arrays):

> So with ‘{}’ you access elements of a cell array, while with ‘()’ you access a sub array of a cell array.